# Automapper mapping function

Tags: automapper

Hello everyone I am trying to achieve something relatively simple in Automapper but I keep on failing.
I am trying to map a property on my Dto with a function expression

```
   .ForMember(dest => dest.HasPaid, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => MapHasPaid(c)))

    private bool MapHasPaid(AppUser src)
    {
        var lastPayment = src.RentPayments.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTo).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lastPayment == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return lastPayment.DateFrom.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date &&
               DateTime.Now.Date <= lastPayment.DateTo.Date;
    }
```

This returns

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean MapHasPaid(xxxx.Models.AppUser)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I tried with a IValueResolver

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<AppUser, HouseMateEntity, bool>
{
    public bool Resolve(AppUser source, HouseMateEntity destination, bool member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var lastPayment = source.RentPayments.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTo).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lastPayment == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return lastPayment.DateFrom.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date &&
               DateTime.Now.Date <= lastPayment.DateTo.Date;
    }
}


.ForMember(dest => dest.HasPaid, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>())
```

but give me the following exception

> Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression

How can I map my property as a result of more complex query?

thanks

I have also tried the simple case on the documentation 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

same error exception

> Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression

Has anyone got ResolveUsing to work? is this an automapper bug?

EDIT:
the only way I could get this working is with the following, and it really smells bad to me

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.HasPaid,
                   opt => opt.MapFrom(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.RentPayments.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTo).FirstOrDefault().DateFrom) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now) &&
                                      DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.RentPayments.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTo).FirstOrDefault().DateTo)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are attempting to use this with AutoMapper's Projection?  The issue is that the `Resolve` functions you are attempting to implement are making calls that are not translatable in LINQ to Entities.  Basically LINQ does not have a mapping between one of the C# calls you're making to some corresponding SQL to run on the database.

The reason your last bit of code works is because you are using the `DbFunctions` class which implements all the necessary logic to handle datetime  manipulation in LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL.

Either use the `DbFunctions` methods exactly like you are or first retrieve the data (call `.ToList()` or similar on the query) and then map to your Target type.

This is documented in the [AutoMapper documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#custom-projection).

**EDIT:**

If you are using the AutoMapper Queryable Extensions then ResolveUsing is NOT supported [AutoMapper documentation: Supported mapping options](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#supported-mapping-options)

Comment: If in my CustomResolver I replace the whole body of the Resolve method with a "return true" it still throw "Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression". As I said in my post, I tried the exact same example in the documentation at  https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers but still giving me the same exception

Comment: If you are using the AutoMapper Queryable Extensions then ResolveUsing is NOT supported:  https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#supported-mapping-options

Comment: so there is no way to accomplish my task?

Comment: You can accomplish your task using the code in your "EDIT" above.  It may smell bad to you, but it works.  If by "my task" you mean using `ResolveUsing`, then no, automapper does not support that when using the queryable extensions per the documentation.

Comment: yw - please upvote and mark answer if the question can be closed.

Comment: More than a correct answer is a "compromise" answer.